# thread safe problem of the CopyOnWriteMap in the Kafka source code

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, atomic

i'm reading the kafka-0.10.1's source code and have a question about the CopyOnWriteMap class, here is part of the implementation of the class:

```
public class CopyOnWriteMap<K, V> implements ConcurrentMap<K, V> {

    private volatile Map<K, V> map;

    @Override
    public synchronized V put(K k, V v) {
        Map<K, V> copy = new HashMap<K, V>(this.map);
        V prev = copy.put(k, v);
        this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(copy);
        return prev;
    }
    
    @Override
    public V get(Object k) {
        return map.get(k);
    }
```

Assuming there are two threads, where Thread A is currently executing the put function with the statement this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(copy); and Thread B is executing the get function with the statement map.get(k).  may not be atomic.

I'm not familiar with Java (I'm sorry for that), but if the operation 'this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(copy)' is not atomic, there is a possibility that Thread B might get an incorrect object. For example, if Thread A is in the middle of executing this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(copy); and Thread B tries to access map.get(k), it could potentially get a 'dirty' value if the modification is not yet complete.(in C++, when assigning a value to an int64, it's possible to perform two separate write operations, modifying the low 32 bits and high 32 bits separately. Therefore, between the first modification and the second modification, the value of this int64 variable becomes 'dirty.')

Comment: There is good answer for you question: [Concurrent access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472280/concurrent-access-to-unmodifiablemap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Wrong assumption.

> I'm not familiar with Java (I'm sorry for that), but if the operation 'this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(copy)' is not atomic

This is wrong - it is atomic.

`unmodifiableMap` **does not make a copy**.

It just creates a wrapper object. This object contains a reference to `copy` (it's all pointers. `copy` is a pointer. the map created by `unmodifiableMap` copies that pointer, it does not make a copy of the map).

This wrapper implements every method in map with a one liner:

1. Any method that modifies things (So, `.clear()`, `.put`, `.putAll`, `.remove`, `.removeIf`, and so on) is implemented with `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unmodifiable");`.
2. Any method that doesn't is implemented as `refToUnderlyingMap.sameMethod()`. e.g. `get(Object key)` is implemented as `return refToUnderlyingMap.get(key);`.

This has the effect of being able to hand the map produced by `unmodifiableMap` to code you don't trust. They can't use this wrapper to modify the actual map. It has absolutely no effect whatsoever on the underlying map. In fact:

```
var map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "one");
var unmod = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
map.put(2, "two");
System.out.println(unmod.get(2));
```

The above would print 'two'. "unmodifiable" does not mean "immutable" / "unchanging". It means literally what it says: **THIS** reference is unmodifiable - it cannot be used to modify the map. But something *else* (that has a ref to the underlying map object that was passed to `Collections.unmodifiableMap` certainly can, and if that other code does this, you'll see that).

The remainder of your question is moot, given that it *is* atomic in this sense.

### Assignment is atomic

`put` is `sychronized` but `get` is not, thus, there is no 'happens-before' relationship established between the writing of the `map` field in `put` and reading it in `get` - that will have to come from elsewhere.

However, java does not just go: "Oh well, just give up, *anything can happen* if you fail to establish HB/HA!". No, the JMM is clear: That means *the update* may or may not be observed from elsewhere. The JVM is not allowed to make up arbitrary values; either `map` is observed to point at the previously created unmodifiable warpper, or to the new one. It can't point at anything else, and assignment is atomic. That `get` method, even though it is not synchronized and even if called from another thread, will see a full, valid reference. It's just unclear to which unmodifiable wrapper map it'll lead. Either 'the old' or 'the new'. Presumably the code has one of these two properties:

1. It doesn't matter which one, the method responds according to designed spec either way.
2. It's the responsibility of the caller to establish HB/HA.